# How do I delegate methodMissing calls to nested classes?

Tags: groovy, dsl, method-missing

I'd like to create a DSL with syntax like:

```
Graph.make {
    foo {
        bar()
        definedMethod1() // isn't missing!
    }
    baz()
}
```

Where when the handler for this tree encounters the outermost closure, it creates an instance of some class, which has some defined methods and also its own handler for missing methods.

I figured this would be easy enough with some structure like:

```
public class Graph {
    def static make(Closure c){
        Graph g = new Graph()
        c.delegate = g
        c()
    }

    def methodMissing(String name, args){
        println "outer " + name
        ObjImpl obj = new ObjImpl(type: name)
        if(args.length > 0 && args[0] instanceof Closure){
            Closure closure = args[0]
            closure.delegate = obj
            closure()
        }
    }

    class ObjImpl {
        String type
        def methodMissing(String name, args){
            println "inner " + name
        }
        def definedMethod1(){ 
                println "exec'd known method"
        }
    }
}
```

But the methodMissing handler interprets the entire closure inside Graph rather than delegating the inner closure to ObjImpl, yielding output:

```
outer foo
outer bar
exec'd known method
outer baz
```

How do I scope the missing method call for the inner closure to the inner object that I create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two problems with this approach:

1. Defining `ObjImpl` within the same context as `Graph` means that any `missingMethod` call will hit `Graph` first
2. Delegation appears to happen locally unless a [`resolveStrategy`](http://java.dzone.com/articles/groovy-resolve-strategies) is set, e.g.:

   ```
   closure.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
   ```

Answer (score 3):

The easy answer is to set the inner closure's `resolveStrategy` to "delegate first", but doing that when the delegate defines a `methodMissing` to intercept *all* method calls has the effect of making it impossible to define a method outside the closure and call it from inside, e.g.

```
def calculateSomething() {
  return "something I calculated"
}

Graph.make {
  foo {
    bar(calculateSomething())
    definedMethod1()
  }
}
```

To allow for this sort of pattern it's better to leave all the closures as the default "owner first" resolve strategy, but have the outer `methodMissing` be aware of when there is an inner closure in progress and hand back down to that:

```
public class Graph {
    def static make(Closure c){
        Graph g = new Graph()
        c.delegate = g
        c()
    }

    private ObjImpl currentObj = null

    def methodMissing(String name, args){
        if(currentObj) {
            // if we are currently processing an inner ObjImpl closure,
            // hand off to that
            return currentObj.invokeMethod(name, args)
        }
        println "outer " + name
        if(args.length > 0 && args[0] instanceof Closure){
            currentObj = new ObjImpl(type: name)
            try {
                Closure closure = args[0]
                closure()
            } finally {
                currentObj = null
            }
        }
    }

    class ObjImpl {
        String type
        def methodMissing(String name, args){
            println "inner " + name
        }
        def definedMethod1(){ 
                println "exec'd known method"
        }
    }
}
```

With this approach, given the above DSL example, the `calculateSomething()` call will pass up the chain of owners and reach the method defined in the calling script.  The `bar(...)` and `definedMethod1()` calls will go up the chain of owners and get a `MissingMethodException` from the outermost scope, then try the delegate of the outermost closure, ending up in `Graph.methodMissing`.  That will then see that there is a `currentObj` and pass the method call back down to that, which in turn will end up in `ObjImpl.definedMethod1` or `ObjImpl.methodMissing` as appropriate.

If your DSL can be nested more than two levels deep then you'll need to keep a stack of "current objects" rather than a single reference, but the principle is exactly the same.

Comment: Ah! Interesting. So this seems like a scoping issue, and can be overcome by scoping through use of the "this" keyword. In particular, calling `this.calculateSomething()` will resolve the method. The advantage of not keeping around the stack is that the code to deal with missing methods in >2 nested closures can be kept in the appropriate context (and I expect to be 3-4 levels deep)

Comment: True, but as most DSLs work owner first the principle of least surprise suggests that you shouldn't have to.  I've added an alternative answer using Groovy's `BuilderSupport` that might work better for you.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the alternate approaches. After some experimentation, I still prefer delegating the behavior of nested closures to a nested object. While it differs from the standard Groovy DSL impl, it seems to provide better separation of concerns, and given both my style and the preferred style of my colleagues, I think will ultimately make the DSL we're working on more maintainable (and that's critical). I'm reworking an implementation that currently uses BuilderSupport, which in my view, is tough to follow. Nevertheless, I've upvoted your answers for your effort and help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach might be to make use of `groovy.util.BuilderSupport`, which is designed for tree building DSLs like yours:

```
class Graph {
  List children
  void addChild(ObjImpl child) { ... }

  static Graph make(Closure c) {
    return new GraphBuilder().build(c)
  }
}

class ObjImpl {
  List children
  void addChild(ObjImpl child) { ... }
  String name

  void definedMethod1() { ... }
}

class GraphBuilder extends BuilderSupport {

  // the various forms of node builder expression, all of which
  // can optionally take a closure (which BuilderSupport handles
  // for us).

  // foo()
  public createNode(name) { doCreate(name, [:], null) }

  // foo("someValue")
  public createNode(name, value) { doCreate(name, [:], value) }

  // foo(colour:'red', shape:'circle' [, "someValue"])
  public createNode(name, Map attrs, value = null) {
    doCreate(name, attrs, value)
  }

  private doCreate(name, attrs, value) {
    if(!current) {
      // root is a Graph
      return new Graph()
    } else {
      // all other levels are ObjImpl, but you could change this
      // if you need to, conditioning on current.getClass()
      def = new ObjImpl(type:name)
      current.addChild(newObj)
      // possibly do something with attrs ...
      return newObj
    }
  }

  /**
   * By default BuilderSupport treats all method calls as node
   * builder calls.  Here we change this so that if the current node
   * has a "real" (i.e. not methodMissing) method that matches
   * then we call that instead of building a node.
   */
  public Object invokeMethod(String name, Object args) {
    if(current?.respondsTo(name, args)) {
      return current.invokeMethod(name, args)
    } else {
      return super.invokeMethod(name, args)
    }
  }
}
```

The way BuilderSupport works, the builder itself is the closure delegate at all levels of the DSL tree.  It calls all its closures with the default "owner first" resolve strategy, which means that you can define a method outside the DSL and call it from inside, e.g.

```
def calculateSomething() {
  return "something I calculated"
}

Graph.make {
  foo {
    bar(calculateSomething())
    definedMethod1()
  }
}
```

but at the same time any calls to methods defined by `ObjImpl` will be routed to the current object (the `foo` node in this example).